# r: convert data into another format

Tags: r

in an experiment I investigated effort in different tasks with two tools.
So I got the following results:

```
  Task1ToolA Task1ToolB Task2ToolA Task2ToolB
P1     3          NA         NA          4
P2     NA         4          5           NA
P3     2          NA         NA          3
```

P1, P2, P3 are my test persons. My variables are Task1ToolA, Task1ToolB, Task2ToolA, Task2ToolB.

I think for evaluation and plotting, I better had the following:

```
     EffortTask1 ToolOfTask1 EffortTask2 ToolOfTask2
P1     3              A           4           B
P2     4              B           5           A
P3     2              A           3           B
```

Each entry in the first table gives rise to two entries in the second table, one for the score and one for the tool. So, how can I convert this? I am a complete beginner to R and ggplot2.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly the two are related? I can't really tell...

Comment: Which "two" do you mean? Actually there were six tasks and two tools. A person solved task1 with toolA, then task2 with toolB, then task3 with toolA again, then task4 with toolB, etc. But the order was randomized. So each tesperson solved in a different order.

Comment: If you mean the two tables: Person1 achieved effort of '3' in task1 with  toolA. This number gives rise to a '3' and a 'A' in the second table. Then person1 had an effort of 4 in task2, solved with toolB, which gives rise of '4' and 'B'.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think that you might benefit from having your data in "long format".

First we recreate your data frame:

```
d <- read.table(text='Task1ToolA Task1ToolB Task2ToolA Task2ToolB
P1     3          NA         NA          4
P2     NA         4          5           NA
P3     2          NA         NA          3', header=TRUE)
```

And now create a new data frame in long format:

```
d_new <- data.frame(
  # person: repeat each of the row names as many times as there 
  #         are columns.
  person=rep(row.names(d), ncol(d)),
  # task: extract the task number (see ?sub), from the column names, 
  #       and repeat each as many times as there are rows.
  task=as.numeric(rep(sub('Task(\\d+).*', '\\1', colnames(d)), each=nrow(d))),
  # tool: similarly, extract the tool number from the column names, 
  #       and repeat each as many times as there are rows.
  tool=rep(sub('.*Tool(.*)', '\\1', colnames(d)), each=nrow(d)),
  # score: reduce the data.frame of scores to a vector.
  score=unlist(d)
)
```

Which looks like:

```
d_new

##             person task tool score
## Task1ToolA1     P1    1    A     3
## Task1ToolA2     P2    1    A    NA
## Task1ToolA3     P3    1    A     2
## Task1ToolB1     P1    1    B    NA
## Task1ToolB2     P2    1    B     4
## Task1ToolB3     P3    1    B    NA
## Task2ToolA1     P1    2    A    NA
## Task2ToolA2     P2    2    A     5
## Task2ToolA3     P3    2    A    NA
## Task2ToolB1     P1    2    B     4
## Task2ToolB2     P2    2    B    NA
## Task2ToolB3     P3    2    B     3
```

Optionally, you can remove the (now confusing) row names, and filter out the rows with `NA` scores:

```
d_new <- na.omit(d_new)
row.names(d_new) <- NULL
d_new

##   person task tool score
## 1     P1    1    A     3
## 2     P3    1    A     2
## 3     P2    1    B     4
## 4     P2    2    A     5
## 5     P1    2    B     4
## 6     P3    2    B     3
```

Comment: Great solution! I also suggest taking a look at [this great paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) about tidy data and the [tidyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) package.

Comment: Thanks @PauloMiraMor - it's on my list - Hadley pumps stuff out too fast!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this (data is called `dat`)

```
res <- do.call(cbind, lapply(split(as.list(dat), grepl("Task2", colnames(dat))), function(x) {
    inds <- is.na(x[[1]])
    setNames(data.frame(ifelse(inds, x[[2]], x[[1]]), ifelse(inds, "B", "A")),
             c("EffortTask", "ToolOfTask"))
}))
setNames(cbind(rownames(dat), res),
         c("person", paste0(sub("[A-Z]+\\.", "", names(res)), rep(1:2, each=2))))
#   person EffortTask1 ToolOfTask1 EffortTask2 ToolOfTask2
# 1     P1           3           A           4           B
# 2     P2           4           B           5           A
# 3     P3           2           A           3           B
```

And (much simpler!), to put it into long format using `tidyr` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)

dat %>% mutate(id=rownames(dat)) %>%
  melt %>% separate(variable, c("task", "tool"), "Tool") %>%
  .[complete.cases(.),]
#    id  task tool value
# 1  P1 Task1    A     3
# 3  P3 Task1    A     2
# 5  P2 Task1    B     4
# 8  P2 Task2    A     5
# 10 P1 Task2    B     4
# 12 P3 Task2    B     3
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `grep` and `max.col` to get the output.

```
d1 <- data.frame(
        lapply(c('Task1', 'Task2'), function(x) {
          x1 <- df1[grep(x, names(df1))]
          i1 <- max.col(!is.na(x1))
          setNames(data.frame(x1[cbind(1:nrow(x1), i1)], LETTERS[i1]), 
                   paste0(c('Effort', 'ToolOf'), x))
       }))
row.names(d1) <- row.names(df1)
d1
#   EffortTask1 ToolOfTask1 EffortTask2 ToolOfTask2
#P1           3           A           4           B
#P2           4           B           5           A
#P3           2           A           3           B
```

---

The steps involved in the above code are as follows. We loop through the strings ('Task1', 'Task2') using `lapply`

```
   lapply(c('Task1', 'Task2'), function(x) {...
```

Then, we subset the columns of 'df1' using `grep`.

```
     ...
     x1 <- df1[grep(x, names(df1))]
     ...
```

Create a column index ('i1') based on the non-NA values of 'x1' with `max.col`.  This basically gives the column index of maximum value for each row.  The `!is.na(x1)` returns a logical matrix of `TRUE/FALSE` values for `non-NA/NA` value.   So, if `TRUE` is for column 2 for row1, it returns 2, likewise, this is done for each row.

```
...
i1 <- max.col(!is.na(x1))
...
```

In the next step, we can create a `data.frame` using the 'i1' index.  We `cbind` it with row index (`1:nrow(x1)`) to create row/column index, this can be used for extracting the elements from 'x1' to create the 'Effort' column.  The 'ToolOf' column is created by using 'i1' as index for the `LETTERS` .

```
...
setNames(data.frame(x1[cbind(1:nrow(x1), i1)], LETTERS[i1]), 
               paste0(c('Effort', 'ToolOf'), x))
...
```

We change the 'list' of 'data.frames' to a single data.frame with the `data.frame` call and change the `row.names` to that of the original dataset.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Task1ToolA = c(3L, NA, 2L), Task1ToolB = c(NA, 
4L, NA), Task2ToolA = c(NA, 5L, NA), Task2ToolB = c(4L, NA, 3L
)), .Names = c("Task1ToolA", "Task1ToolB", "Task2ToolA", "Task2ToolB"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("P1", "P2", "P3"))
```